# Java Passing Parameters Best Practice

Tags: java, design-patterns, parameter-passing

Which approach is the best practice in Java - ORM - RestFul Services?

1. Get a User JSON from a Client
2. Create a User object like : `User user = JSON_to_User_Object_method`
3. Call the service method to add user, and pass the User object like : `service.addUser(User user)`

**or**

1. Get a User JSON from a Client
2. Call the service method to add user **but** pass the Json values to the service's method like : `service.addUser(jsonobject.name, jsonobject.surname, ...)`
3. And handle the other stuff in the service method named `addUser`,(create User Pojo, end persist and so on..)

Comment: I would create one more layer in between Servlet layer and service layer. May be a parser layer. That would keep everything tied up.

Comment: Don't create useless layers, you will end up with translation of translations of translations... Consider your JSon object as a DTO and use it as-this.

Comment: With using proper frameworks you won't need to worry about the JSON-2-Object conversion yourself. So the first way is clearly best practice. Such frameworks would be JaxRS or Spring MVC - for example.